# Make asp panel visible through an asp checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, panel, checkbox

**asp panel should be make visible through an asp check box using a java-script function**

My company wants me to change a coding on a particular page, the requirement is that when you click a check box, a panel should become visible but it should not be post-back. 
So they asked me to use JavaScript and implement this requirement.

I tried this code and as I see it, the JavaScript function can not find the id as the panel will be created dynamically. So can anyone please help me to do this?

Important : it should stop post-back!!!

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun1()
    {
       if (document.getElementById("CheckBox1").checked == true)
       {
          document.getElementById("Panel3").visible = true;
       }
    }
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="89px">
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnClick="fun1()" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="91px" Visible="False">
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <br />
       <br />
       <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
</form>
```

Comment: sorry document.getElementById("Panel3").visible = true;

Answer (score 1):

It should help you...

```
var panelControls = document.getElementById("<%=mypanel.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < panelControls .length; i++)
        panelControls [i].disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Panel is a server side control, when it renders to the browser it renders as a DIV HTML element, you should use

```
function toogleDisplay(sender)
{
if(sender.checked)
    document.getElementById('<%= Panel3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
else
  document.getElementById('<%= Panel3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
}
```

and for your asp checkbox control you should add this code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          checkbox1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "toogleDisplay(this);");
Panel3.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
    }
```

Comment: The name 'checkbox1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Replace it with CheckBox1,
Actually this is the ID of your asp checkbox control,
You should replace it with ID of your checkbox control.

Comment: my mistake yogi. i put da wrong ID. but it still not working . the page loads with a "error on page" <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"   /> its the checkbox control should i use a OnClick inside checkbox controle?? and your post help me alot to understand the situation.

Comment: No OnClick inside the checkbox control is used to fire a server side event but here we want to fire a client side event (toogleDisplay()) on checkbox's click.
Please elaborate the error you are facing currently after applying my code.

Comment: the compilation does not give any errors yogi, but the page without any content. i think it have to do smthing with <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="91px" Visible="False">
this code yogi. i set it  Visible="False". although i click the checkbox, it wont appear.

Comment: No don't set `<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="91px" Visible="False">`,
use my updated code in answer for hiding the panel.

Comment: bt yogi, the panel should not appear when the page loads. and when the check box checked, the panel should appear. do we have to set style visibility to none in page load. or can i jst set the property visible fales.?? i wd be so glad if u could help me with this.

Comment: Yes `Panel3.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");` code will hide your panel on load

Comment: thanks for the help anyways yogi. i dont kw wts wrong here. bt nways thanks for the help again.